# Can 1 primary id link to multiple ids in one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

I am trying to create a database schema regarding betting being played with numerous betting providers. Some betting providers have 15/13/16 etc games per pool.

E.g. Provider A (ID 1) has Liverpool Vs Man City has 1 of its 15 games and Provider B (ID 2) also has this match for one of their 13 games.

Can I record this like the following;

```
Match ID 1
Provider ID 1,2
Home Team Liverpool
Away Team Man.City
Bookmaker Pinnacle
```

Is that possible or can SQL not store to id's for 1 primary id?

I am trying to keep a record of each match for each pool so I can then record what the betting prices were by specific bookmakers and what the payout percentages were for future references.

Is there anyway this can be done?

E.g. Provider A (ID 1) has Liverpool Vs Man City has 1 of its 15 games and Provider B (ID 2) also has this match for one of their 13 games.
Can I record this like the following;

```
Match ID 1
Provider ID 1,2
Home Team Liverpool
Away Team ManCity
Bookmaker Pinnacle
```

Is that possible or can SQL not store to id's for 1 primary id?

Not coded yet, currently working on creating the database schema

Comment: Please AVOID putting more than one key in a single column and making a comma delimited list of keys. That just make processing that info very much more difficult in raw SQL. Instead use one or more link tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding with foreign keys. If you think you need to store two IDs in one record's foreign key, your foreign key is in the wrong place.

In your case, if a match can have many bettors, and a bettor can have many matches, you need a many-to-many or "junction" table, linking matches to bettors.

Your schema might look something like this:

```
table matches:

id  | Home Team | Away Team
----+-----------+-----------
 1  | Liverpool | Man.City


table providers:

id  | name
----+------------
  1 | Provider A
  2 | Provider B


table provider_matches:

provider_id | match_id
------------+----------
      1     |    1
      2     |    1
```

Your table `provider_matches` now has two foreign keys, which can be enforced through foreign key constraints, linking both providers to the same match.

Comment: Right, so the best way is basically having to repeat the information? so it could be for example
Provider 1 Match ID 1
Provider 2 Match ID 1
Provider 3 Match ID 1
Provider 4 Match ID 1

Comment: There is no repeated information here, each piece of information exists exactly once, in one place, connected together with constraints that enforce relational integrity. You probably want to think of a better name for the `provider_matches` table, and figure out what additional pieces of information exist in that table, such as an "amount" for a bet.

Comment: @kree Just a note that you should further normalize this schema so that you're not repeating information like team name

Comment: I have two tables.. 1 table for home team.. where each team has its own id and then 1 table for away team.. where each team again has its own id? What do you think?!